# Get text between specific characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some codes like below.

```
<table class="formulaTablePopular">
    <tr>
        <td class="forma">
            <input type="hidden" value="0" id="F01"/>
            <div class="formulaOk" id="F01Div"
                 onclick="toggleFormulu(this, 'F01');"
                 onmouseover="toggleFormuluOver(this);"
                 onmouseout="toggleFormuluOut(this);">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slika">
            $$ a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)\left(a^2 - ab + b^2\right) $$
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<table class="formulaTablePopular">
    <tr>
        <td class="forma">
            <input type="hidden" value="0" id="F02"/>
            <div class="formulaOk" id="F02Div"
                 onclick="toggleFormulu(this, 'F02');"
                 onmouseover="toggleFormuluOver(this);"
                 onmouseout="toggleFormuluOut(this);">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slika">
            $$ a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)\left(a^2 + ab + b^2\right) $$
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>

<table class="formulaTablePopular">
    <tr>
        <td class="forma">
            <input type="hidden" value="0" id="F03"/>
            <div class="formulaOk" id="F03Div"
                 onclick="toggleFormulu(this, 'F03');"
                 onmouseover="toggleFormuluOver(this);"
                 onmouseout="toggleFormuluOut(this);">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="slika">
            $$ a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) $$
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

How i can Get all text between `$$` character?
i need to delete all text except these code

```
$$ a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)\left(a^2 - ab + b^2\right) $$
$$ a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)\left(a^2 + ab + b^2\right) $$
$$ a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) $$
```

Is possible do this in notepad++?

Comment: Regex and HTML doesn't go well. Consider using some parser instead. If you can use Java you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to get only text you want with 3 lines of code http://pastebin.com/NiEPHLj2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find what:

```
^.*$(?<!\$\$)
```

And replace with nothing. Make sure you've unchecked "*`.` matches newline*" option.

Explanation:

```
^        # assert position at the beginning of the line
.*       # matches as much text (except newlines) as possible
$        # assert position at the end of the line
(?<!     # a negative lookbehind: looks behind to see if there is '$$', 
         # and if not, causes the pattern to fail
  \$\$   # match '$$' literally
)        # end of lookbehind
```

Comment: Thanks @Amal Murali for answer. this find all text between `$$` character and need to copy one by one. is possible to delete all text that not between `$$`.

Comment: WOW! Nice answer. You really saved my time.

Comment: Compact and efficient. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following, this will remove everything except these patterns.

```
Find: [^$]*(\${2}[^$]+\${2})[^$]*
Replace: \1\n
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tV3jR5/2)